# SSRS - Database Result Not Match with Report

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

When I put the following query for my database is empty and declare R.UserID='1'
[Database Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9I9n.png)

AND

and when I enter 1 in the report, the report show the following result
[SSRS Report Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMBL6.png)

I totally no have idea to solve this error and what is the error.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the type of the `UserID` column?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen bigint
refer to the screenshot
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ecd94f6f-daaf-482f-8f7e-8d174660ab9f/ssrs-database-result-ssrs-report-result-not-match?forum=sqlreportingservices